# Magento skip update product price if zero

Tags: php, magento

I am using a function to automatically update product prices in Magento, but sometimes the supplier doesn't add a price for a product.
I would like to skip the product price update for a certain product if the value is zero (so I can manually put in a price).
Please see the code below. I tried to use `$product->setPrice($price != 0);` but that didn't work. My code is:

```
public function updateProductPriceAndStock($sku)
{
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    if($_product)
    {
        $product =  Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());
        $product->setStockData($this->getProductStockFromErp($sku));
        $product->setCost($this->getProductCostFromErp($sku));
        $price = $this->getProductPriceFromErp($sku);
        $product->setPrice($price);
        $product->setMsrp($price);
        $product->save();
        $this->_counts++;
        unset($product);
    }
    unset($_product);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$product->setPrice($price != 0);` is same as `$product->setPrice(true/false);`

Maybe something like this?

```
public function updateProductPriceAndStock($sku) {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
       if($_product){
        $product =  Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());
        $product->setStockData($this->getProductStockFromErp($sku));
        $product->setCost($this->getProductCostFromErp($sku));
        $price = $this->getProductPriceFromErp($sku);
        if($price != 0){
            $product->setPrice($price);
            $product->setMsrp($price);
        }
        $product->save(); // put this inside above "if" if you want to skip update (database save)
        $this->_counts++;
        unset($product);
    }
    unset($_product);
}
```